# Understanding an application's cmd arguments

Tags: windows, command-line, command-line-arguments, cmd.exe

I'm testing out an application and its sourcecode gives no clues as to the actual syntax other than the help output.

I have tried many combinations trying to get it to work, and it keeps outputting me the help screen due to invalid syntax. Here is the usage:

```
Usage is : ngenerator <options> filepath|directorypath
Where <options> may be :

        -h : print this help notice
        -d : Tell NGenerator that the supplied path is a directory path -o filename : write the source code in filename
        -u Unsafe|Safe[UnsafeWithWrapper : the degree of "unsafeness" of the source, see man
```

Now if you were looking at this, what would the correct way for it to work be? The program has absolutely no documentation, and it is from a dead project. Upon first look can you give me what you would think would be the proper way to enter the syntax?

Comment: The actual usage seems straightforward - use `ngenerator -d <directory>` to run the program on a directory, and `ngenerator -o <filepath>` to run it on a file. No idea what's meant by "unsafeness", though - can you provide any more information (the man page or source code)?

Comment: I have tried running it like ngenerator -d C:\test , also ngenerator -d "C:\test" , also ngenerator -o C:\test\app.h and with quotes around the path on that as well...everytime I keep getting a system.argumentnullexception. Here is the page, you can download the code on the page if you want. This is all there is to go by. [URL](http://repo.or.cz/w/ngenerator.git)

Comment: I can't run it now, but from a cursory look at the code, I think it wants something like `ngenerator -d:<directory>` - obviously that wouldn't work with an absolute path (it doesn't appear to escape the string), but try running `ngenerator -d:test` from C:.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question title.. The output from command-line help **should** be standard. Generally Linux tends to be more consistent than windows, but this is generally how they can be understood:

```
C:\>attrib /?
Displays or changes file attributes.

ATTRIB [+R | -R] [+A | -A ] [+S | -S] [+H | -H] [+I | -I]
       [drive:][path][filename] [/S [/D] [/L]]
...
```

The rules are usually as follows:

- Anything in `[]` is optional
- Optional parameters may be nested: `[/S [/D] [/L]]` means you may optionally provide `/S` and if you do, you can also optionally provide `/D` and/or `/L`
- Some parameters are an 'either/or' situation: `[+R | -R]` means you may optionally specify either `+R` or `-R` but not both.

Here's another example:

```
Usage: ping [-t] [-a] [-n count] [-l size] [-f] [-i TTL] [-v TOS]
            [-r count] [-s count] [[-j host-list] | [-k host-list]]
            [-w timeout] [-R] [-S srcaddr] [-4] [-6] target_name
```

Note that Windows sometimes uses `-` and sometimes uses `/` to prefix parameters (sigh). This shows you that some optional parameters, such as `-n` also need a value, `count` and also that `target_name` is mandatory because it is not in `[]`

**The output of ngenerator:**

```
Usage is : ngenerator <options> filepath|directorypath
Where <options> may be :

        -h : print this help notice
        -d : Tell NGenerator that the supplied path is a directory path -o filename : write the source code in filename
        -u Unsafe|Safe[UnsafeWithWrapper : the degree of "unsafeness" of the source, see man
```

...Is very poor. Looking at this I would try: `ngenerator -o c:\file.h`. Does it want `c:\file.h` to already exist? Looking at the repository there is a horrific amount of code to parse such a simple command line, which doesn't give much confidence in the app. Does it need `C:\\file.h` ?